# How to understand inaccurate results while using numpy.log?

Tags: python, numpy

I wish to calculate the natural logarithm of a value that is very close to 1, but not exactly one.

For example, `np.log(1 + 1e-22)` is 0 and not some non-zero value. However, `np.log(1 + 1e-13)` is not zero, and calculated to be `9.992007221625909e-14`.

How can I understand this tradeoff of precision while using a numpy function vs. defining a numpy array with `dtype` as `np.longdouble`?

Floating precision information of numpy (v1.22.2) on the system I am using:

```
>>> np.finfo(np.longdouble)
finfo(resolution=1e-15, min=-1.7976931348623157e+308, max=1.7976931348623157e+308, dtype=float64)

>>> 1 + np.finfo(np.longdouble).eps
1.0000000000000002
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you are asking. It seems you do understand the limitations of floating-point arithmetic, so what do you *not* understand?

Comment: I am not able to understand the difference between resolution and min\max value of `np.finfo(np.longdouble)`. When I am storing values, they can take values as small as `1e-144`. However, while using `np.log`, as soon as I add value to 1 that are of the order 16 or lesser, I get zero as the output. What am I missing here? :)

Comment: Put it simply, floating point numbers are internally stored like a scientific notation. You can store very small numbers in it because the exponent can be very small, but 1.0+epsilon will not be very precise. In fact for 64-bit numbers used by Numpy the exponent of epsilon cannot be smaller than about 1e-16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete the good solution of @yut23 using Numpy. If you need to deal with very small floats that does not fit in native types defined by Numpy or numbers close to 1 with a precision more than ~10 digits, then you can use the **decimal package**. It is **slower than native float** but it can gives you an **arbitrary precision**. The thing is it does not support the natural logarithm (ie. `log`) function directly since it is based on the transcendental Euler number (ie. `e`) which can hardly be computed with an arbitrary precision (at least not when the precision is huge). Fortunately, you can compute the natural logarithm from the based-10 logarithm and a precomputed Euler number based on existing number databases like [this one](https://www.boxentriq.com/code-breaking/euler-number) (I guess 10000 digits should be enough for your needs ;) ). Here is an example:

```py
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal

decimal.setcontext(decimal.Context(prec=100)) # 100 digits of precision
e = Decimal('2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407663035354759457138217852516643')
result = (Decimal("1")+Decimal("1e-13")).log10() / e.log10()

# result = 9.999999999999500000000000033333333333330833333333333533333333333316666666666668095238095237970238087E-14
```

The precision of `result` is of 99 digits (only the last one is not correct).

Answer (score 2):

For practical usage, take a look at `np.log1p(x)`, which computes `log(1 + x)` without the roundoff error that comes from `1 + x`. From the docs:

> For real-valued input, log1p is accurate also for x so small that 1 + x == 1 in floating-point accuracy.

Even the seemingly working example of `log(1 + 1e-13)` differs from the true value at the 3rd decimal place with 64-bit floats, and at the 6th with 128-bit floats (true value is from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=log%281%2B1e-13%29)):

```
>>> (1 + 1e-13) - 1
9.992007221626409e-14
>>> np.log(1 + 1e-13)
9.992007221625909e-14
>>> np.log(1 + np.array(1e-13, dtype=np.float128))
9.999997791637127032e-14
>>> np.log1p(1e-13)
9.9999999999995e-14
>>> 9.999999999999500000000000033333333333330833333333333533333*10**-14
9.9999999999995e-14
```

Comment: Good solution! Note that `np.float128` is not actually a 128-bit float despite the name. The documentation states it is a "*`long double` but not necessarily with IEEE 754 quadruple-precision*". In fact, on x86-64 systems, it should be a 80-bit float. On some other systems it is a 64-bit one.